# How do you create a local and editable copy of a feature service?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, feature-service

I am creating an app for a local fire department. I have acquired fire hydrant location data from:

http://gisweb.wsscwater.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/FireHydrant/FireBook/MapServer/0

I have imported it as a feature service in ArcGIS Desktop, however I cannot edit the data. I am trying to make a copy (maybe as a shp file) and start with that data to edit it.

Is this possible? Or is there a workaround since I cannot access it (I have asked multiple times but they have not granted as yet)?

Comment: What happens when you add the feature service and then right-click the resultant layer name to choose Data > Export Data?